# In attempting to minimize cold start time for Firebase Cloud functions, how to import a class for use inside one function?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

If I have a module that is only required for one of my Firebase Cloud functions, this [Firebase Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v3eG9xpzNXM&list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM&index=7&t=0s) suggests importing that module inside just the function that needs it, in order to minimize cold start time for all other functions in a project.

This makes sense, but is it also possible to import a class which contains its own set of dependencies inside of a function?

I have a need to use Bcrypt but only in two of my functions. So I would rather not have to load it for all of my other cloud functions where it is not needed.

In my application, I have the following import:

```
import BcryptTool from './classes/bcrypt'; // <--- only needed in 2 functions
```

Here is the contents of `bcrypt.ts`:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';
export default class BcryptTool {
 public static hashValue(value: string, rounds: number, callback: (error: Error, hash: string) => void) : void {
      bcrypt.hash(value, rounds, (error:any, hash:any) => {
            callback(error, hash);
      });
 }
 public static compare(value: string, dbHash: string, callback: (error: string | null, match: boolean | null) => void) {
    bcrypt.compare(value, dbHash, (err: Error, match: boolean) => {
        if(match) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback('Invalid value match', null);
        }
    });
 }
}
```

And finally, in my Firebase Cloud functions `index.ts`:

```
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });
admin.initializeApp();
const util = express();
const api = express();
...
import BcryptTool from './classes/bcrypt'; // <-- when i import here, calls to its methods within my functions work as expected
...
util.use(cors);
util.post('/verify', async (request: any, response: any) => {

  // according to Doug's answer below i should be able to attempt to import here as a solution using a dynamic import expression like so:

  const BcryptTool = await import('./classes/bcrypt');

  // but the following subsequent call to .compare() fails

  BcryptTool.compare(...)

  // VS Code hinting shows an error: Property 'compare' does not exist on type 'typeof import('FULL/PATH/TO/CLASS/classes/bcrypt')'

});

api.use(cors);
api.post('/endpoint/foo', async (request: any, response: any) => {
  // I do not need Bcrypt here
});
api.post('/endpoint/bar', async (request: any, response: any) => {
  // I do not need Bcrypt here
});
```

Is this not possible? Am I just doing it all wrong?*

Comment: I have voted to close this as a duplicate: [What is the correct way to dynamically import a class inside of a Firebase Cloud function using typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893797/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dynamically-import-a-class-inside-of-a-firebase-cloud)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, you can [async (dynamic) import](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html#dynamic-import-expressions) anywhere you want in TypeScript code.  The imported symbols will be visible in the scope where you imported it, and nowhere else.  It doesn't matter what the module contains.

Comment: Thanks, although i tried this, and vs code complains when i attempt to call a method in my class after i await the import: `const BcryptTool = await import('./classes/bcrypt.class')`  followed by a call to `BcryptTool.compare()` results in VS code complaining that `Property 'compare' does not exist on type 'typeof import('./classes/bcrypt.class')`. If i set BcryptTool to a type of `any`, the functions will compile and deploy to firebase, but the call to my `compare` method fails.

Comment: OK, sounds like you're doing something wrong,  Please ask a new question that better describes what you're doing, and how the code isn't working the way you expect.

Comment: When i import the class into the global scope as outlined in my question above, the code works without issue. It is when i attempt to dynamically import the class inside a function using the method you describe that is causing the problem.

Comment: Yes, I understand.  Could you pose a new question that illustrates this clearly?  Burying all this information in comments that are difficult to read is not helping the chances of someone being able to identify and resolve the issue.

Comment: I posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893797/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dynamically-import-a-class-inside-of-a-firebase-cloud

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted answer on behalf of the question author, to move it from the question post)*.

I was not importing the class correctly. The reason along with a solution is outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58893797/what-is-the-correct-way-to-dynamically-import-a-class-inside-of-a-firebase-cloud).