# What is the correct way to dynamically import a class inside of a Firebase Cloud function using typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

**In a Firebase Cloud Function project...**

I have the following typescript file at the root of my `src` directory right along side of my main `index.ts` file which imports one dependency and exports a class that includes 2 methods. This file is titled `bcrypt.class.ts`:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

export default class BcryptTool {
  public static hashValue(value: string, rounds: number, callback: (error: Error, hash: string) => void) : void {
      bcrypt.hash(value, rounds, (error:any, hash:any) => {
            callback(error, hash);
      });
  }
  public static compare(value: string, dbHash: string, callback: (error: string | null, match: boolean | null) => void) {
    bcrypt.compare(value, dbHash, (err: Error, match: boolean) => {
        if(match) {
            callback(null, true);
        } else {
            callback('Invalid value match', null);
        }
    });
  }
}
```

In my Firebase Cloud functions `index.ts` file I import this class and make a call to it's 'compare' method within one of my functions without issue, this works as expected:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const api = express();

import BcryptTool from './bcrypt.class'; // <-- i import the class here

// and use it in a function

api.use(cors);
api.post('/credentials', async (request: any, response: any) => {

   BcryptTool.compare(...) // <--- calls to this method succeed without issue

});
```

**The problem**

My application includes many functions, but I only need the class noted above in one of them, so in an attempt to optimize cold start time for all my other functions, I attempt to dynamically import this class inside of the function that needs it instead of importing it into the global scope as outlined above. This does not work and I cannot figure out why:

```
'use strict';
const express = require('express');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const cors = require('cors')({ origin: true });

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

const api = express();

api.use(cors);
api.post('/credentials', async (request: any, response: any) => {

   const BcryptTool = await import('./bcrypt.class'); // <-- when i attempt to import here instead

   BcryptTool.compare(...) // <--- subsequent calls to this method fail

   // Additionally, VS Code hinting displays a warning: Property 'compare' does not exist on type 'typeof import('FULL/PATH/TO/MY/bcrypt.class')' 

});
```

Is my class not written or exported correctly?

Am I not importing the class correctly inside of my cloud function?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The top-level import (`import BcryptTool from './bcrypt.class';`) will automatically import the `default` export from the `bcrypt.class` module. However, when using the import statement as a function (so called "dynamic import"), it will import the **module** itself, not the default export.

You can see the difference when you would `console.log(BcryptTool)` both imports:

- `import BcryptTool from './bcrypt.class'` will show `{ default: { [Function: BcryptTool] hashValue: [Function], compare: [Function] } }`
- `const BcryptTool = await require('bcrypt.class')` will show `{ [Function: BcryptTool] hashValue: [Function], compare: [Function] }`

Did you notice the `default` in the first console.log? That shows you imported the module, not the default.

Now actually the `import BcryptTool from './bcrypt.class'` syntax is syntactic sugar for doing `import { default as BcryptTool } from './bcrypt.class'`. If you apply this knowledge on the dynamic import, you could do this:

```js
const BcryptToolModule = await import('./bcrypt.class');
BcryptToolModule.default.compare(...);
```

Or in a cleaner syntax:

```js
const { default: BcryptTool } = await import('./bcrypt.class');
BcryptTool.compare(...);
```

Comment: Excellent detail, each example works perfectly. Is there any advantage or disadvantage here given that i am exporting as the default function? Should i just be exporting the class without the 'default' notation?

Comment: I think your default export is just fine, as far as I know it's only a difference in syntax.